# Data grouped by year and month. How do I get the value for that specific month?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm currently trying to organise my data by year, then month, and see the 'total fare' for that month. I've managed to group the data by years and months, but I can't figure out how to get the 'total fare' for that month.

My Current group query looks like this:

```
{
    $group: {
        _id : "$year", month: { $addToSet: "$month" },
        "totalFare" : { "$sum": "$fare"}
    }
}
```

which sorts the data like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubepL.png)

As you can see the totalFare is showing the fare for the year, instead of the months. I've tried using the $addToSet function to add the totalfare too, but i'm getting errors when i try that. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

After spending another hour on it. I've managed to find a solution. I needed to add another group before hand to organise the data by year and month, then format the results using another group.

```
{
    $group: {
        '_id': {
            "month": "$month",
            "year": "$year",
        },
        "totalFare" : { "$sum": "$fare"}
    }
},
{
    $group: {
        _id : "$_id.year", 
        month: { 
            "$addToSet": {
                "monthName": "$_id.month",
                "totalFare": "$totalFare"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This provides the following [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/krgLQ.png)

Hopefully this is useful for anyone with a similar problem!